# Unity3d not working correctly with Mac OS high Sierra

Tags: unity-game-engine, macos-high-sierra

I have updated my os to high Sierra yesterday.
Since update unity3d is not working.
The problem is when I want to open an existing project then unity acts as it's doing something but nothing is happening.
The project never opens.
I tried to reinstall unity but it didn't help.
Is there any way to solve this problem excepts downgrade to Mac OS Sierra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to read the [official post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-and-macos-10-13-high-sierra.474527/) on this topic. The possible solution for the trouble like this is:

> we were able to track down missing Project View items issue as APFS and Unity editor interoperability problem. We are working on a fix, though meanwhile we recommend to not upgrade your main filesystem to APFS or at least keep Unity editor and your projects on HFS+ partition.